# Python argument types did not match c++ signature - Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am just starting to explore using Boost.Python to wrap some c++ code.  I am starting with a toy problem to work out the basic issues but don't understand the error I'm getting.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/args.hpp>


class Parameters
{
public:
    int a;
    void seta(int val) { a = val; }
    int geta() { return a; }
    void add(int first, int second) { a = first + second; }

};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_lib) {

    boost::python::class_<Parameters>("Parameters")
        .add_property("a", &Parameters::geta, &Parameters::seta)
        .def("add", &Parameters::add, boost::python::args("first", "second"));

}
```

The python script, also simple is:

```
#Test program to use simple c++ dynamic library binding

import sys
import my_lib
import ctypes

if __name__ == '__main__':

 
    my_lib.Parameters.a = 9

    result = my_lib.Parameters.a

    print("result = ",result)

    my_lib.Parameters.add(2,3)

    sumresult = badprog_lib1.Parameters.a

    print("sum result = ", sumresult)
```

When I run the python, I get the following:

```
result =  9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/strat/source/repos/badprog_lib1/LibClient2.py", line 19, in <module>
    my_lib.Parameters.add(2,3)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Parameters.add(int, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    add(class Parameters {lvalue}, int first, int second)
```

It is complaining about parameter mismatch between the c++ and Boost.Python arguments.  One thing I don't understand is why the C++ signature includes "class Parameters {lvalue}" and am wondering if that's a clue.  Any help from you more experienced Boost users would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually the line in the c++ file: "sumresult = badprog_lib1.Parameters.a" should have been "sumresult = my_lib.Parameters.a" - I just missed it in the edit.  The error was generated before this line was executed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python code is invalid.

`my_lib.Parameters.a = 9` creates static variable in class `Parameters` that is why it "works".
Then you try call static  method `add` which doesn't exists, `add` is instance method so you need instance of `Parameters` to call it.

So this should work:

```py
import sys
import my_lib
import ctypes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    param = my_lib.Parameters()
    param.add(2, 3)
    print("result = ", param.a)
```